# Gulp - multiple html files - how to display a chosen one in localhost:3000?

Tags: html, gulp, browser-sync

My issue is:
I have a project with several html files representing separate pages. I would like to be able to see one page a time in a browser under localhost:3000 address. The project file structure is as shown on a picture:
[image]

I have set up a gulp in a way to display html under localhost:3000. However, I have no idea how to see each page separately in a browser. It displayed only one of them when I put it on the same level with "styles.scss".

This is my gulpfile.js:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();

gulp.task('serve', ['sass'], function() {

    browserSync.init({
        server: "./app"
    });

    gulp.watch("app/**/*.scss", ['sass']);
    gulp.watch("app/*.html").on('change', browserSync.reload);
});

// Compile sass into CSS & auto-inject into browsers
gulp.task('sass', function() {
    return gulp.src("app/**/*.scss")
        .pipe(sass())
        .pipe(gulp.dest("app/css"))
        .pipe(browserSync.stream());
});

gulp.task('default', ['serve']);
```

Is it something that I should put in gulp to have those htmls rendered in a browser? I wouldn't like to change much the structure of files.

Comment: Shouldn't this question be about Browsersync instead? Gulp is just an automation tool.

Comment: I think that you are right. I did not think about it as both of them are new to me.

Comment: In that case, is your purpose to quickly test changes in the HTML files during development, or serve the pages as a website? If the former, then you're in the right direction; if the latter then you probably want to look into Express.

Comment: Well, it does not necessarily need to be a website - my intention is rather to have a possibilty to write address "localhost:3000/home" or "localhost:3000/subpage" and have respective pages displayed.

Comment: Then you are looking for a web server. Look into Express, the commonly used Node server.

Comment: OK :) Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding the "index": "home.html" to your browserSync options like:

```
gulp.task('serve', ['sass'], function() {

  browserSync.init({
    server: "./app",
    index: "home.html"
  });

  gulp.watch("app/**/*.scss", ['sass']);
  gulp.watch("app/*.html").on('change', browserSync.reload);
});
```

If that doesn't work for some reason, you can try:

```
server: {
  baseDir: "./pathtoYourDirectoryWithTheHTML",
  index: "home.html"
},
```

As for switching between html pages within the same running instance of browserSync I don't know that you can do that.  But you can start another browserSync server via:

```
var browserSync2 = require('browser-sync').create();
```

That's the whole point of create().  And then another gulp task just like your 'serve" but that uses browserSync2 and "index":"yourOtherPage".

Comment: Thanks! Your tips helped me. I managed to have different pages rendered when using different gulp tasks and browsersyncs. However somehow gulp stopped refreshing html automatically and I had to do the refresh manually. But anyway I have the pages rendered :)

Comment: ,Thanks a lot! It took me a while to have time to get back to the project with this problem but finally I managed. I changed my file following your suggestions, I changed the structure of folders (I put all html files directly under "app" folder) and it works perfectly! And much better than with my previous implementation. I also removed the "files" and still the changes are rendered automatically.

Comment: And all works withing one instance of browserSync :)

Answer (score 1):

I managed to have some result based on: [Browsersync not reloading all pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32764850/browsersync-not-reloading-all-pages)

Based on it I changed my gulp to:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();

gulp.task('watch', function() {
    gulp.watch('app/**/*.scss', ['sass']);
    gulp.watch('app/**/*.html').on('change', browserSync.reload);
    browserSync.init({
      files: ['app/pages/home/home.html','app/pages/subpage/subpage.html'],
      server:{
        baseDir:'app',
        directory: true
      }
    });
});

gulp.task('sass', function() {
    return gulp.src('app/**/*.scss')
        .pipe(sass())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('app/css'))
        .pipe(browserSync.stream());
});
```

As an effect, I can access all the pages by changing the address in an URL, for example:

http://localhost:3000/pages/subpage/subpage.html 
or
http://localhost:3000/pages/home/home.html

Comment: Glad you got it working, but the files option is only for watching changes to files.  It doesn't have anything to do with your ability to load them under localhost.  But I was wrong with my statement that you may need to start anther instance of browserSync to serve another html page.  I can happily switch back and forth between html pages with the original code I showed you IF the files are in the same direcctory.  It just makes the "index" page the default.  BUT that is overridden with the "directory": true - which is the key for you.

Comment: You should just know that it is not the "files"  option that is making it work for you.  But it should be watching those files for changes which you probably want anyway.

Comment: Do you consider my files as being in the same directory if each of them has a different parent folder, for example: pages/home/home.html, pages/subpage/subpage.html?

Comment: No, I should have said "in the same folder."  The most immediate parent directory.       My original code works just fine, it loads 'home.html'  as the default [http://localhost:3000/] ,  but you can add 'another.html' to the end of that to go to another file.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that has multiple HTML files, you want to serve on a local server, e.g. `http://localhost:3000/blog`.

Don't forget to try `http://localhost:3000/blog.html`.